# Data migration : from postgreSQL (Azure ) to planetscale

Tags: postgresql, azure, planetscale

I need to migrate my data from  postgreSQL (Azure ) to planetscale which is Mysql based , i have set up my planet scale , along side the schemas .

What should i be be doing next ?

Answer (score 0):

As per [this](https://planetscale.com/docs/reference/mysql-compatibility) planet scale is only compatible with the MY SQL.

[image]

AFAIK we can't migrate database from PostegreSQL to MY SQL server directly. So by using third party tools like data factory copy all data from PostegreSQL to Azure Database for MySQL. You can check [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-postgresql?tabs=data-factory) for reference.

After copying data collect below details of Azure Database for MySQL.

- Server name
- Server admin login name
- Server admin password
- Database name

[image]

Configure the fire wall rules according to the requirements

[image]

Configure Server settings:

[image]

In PlanetScale dashboard, click on "New database", and then select "Import database". Fill the form using the collected information. Also make sure the "SSL Verification" field is set to "Verify certificate and hostname". Click "Connect to database" and the import tool will attempt to connect to your Azure MySQL instance.

[image]

If it connected successfully the import will start and will complete successfully. For more information you can refer [this](https://planetscale.com/docs/imports/azure-database-for-mysql-migration-guide).